# What is the double/int value equivalent to null?

Tags: java, null, int, double

For `String`s I can do `String s = null` since `String` is an object in java. For `chars` I can do `char c = '\u0000';` because that is a "null" character (I could also use blank space character). My question is, for int/double **primative** types what is the equivalent to null (if any)? I don't want to use `0` because in the event that one of my values is actually `0` this won't work.

Note: I need this because I'm parsing and tokenizing from a file and if the parsing fails to parse an int/double it needs to set its return value to something for its invoking class to check.

Comment: One of the reasons that Wrapper Classes came into java is to provide such capability. All you should do is replace your `int` with `Integer`, `double` with `Double`, `char` with `Character` and so on. Then you can assign `null` to these variables as well.

Comment: @STaefi well let me ask you a question. I'm writing my own programming language which is why I needed this. For my basic operations methods should I be using the wrapper classes or primitive data types?

Comment: This question is very opinion based because we are not informed about all aspects of your programming language. Some good features of wrapper classes like auto boxing/unboxing along with OOP like behaviors is very tempting but primitive datatypes may give you higher performance. So can not give you a good idea with this information from you question.

Comment: @STaefi oh okay. Well performance isn't a huge thing for me considering that this is just for fun (ppcg stack exchange site). I guess I'll go with the wrapper classes. TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application defined.

0 may work for some applications.  Any negative number may work for others. For doubles/floats you could use `NaN` (aka Not a number) via `double x = Double.NaN;`

Comment: @Codebender perfect thank you. Will accept this one.

Comment: @Codebender out of sheer curiosity: what happens if I do int i = (int) Double.NaN;? Does this cast successfully?

Comment: @AshwinGupta, no... It will be lossy... It will become `0` mostly... You can easily try it out...

Comment: @Codebender Okay thanks. I couldn't try it I was on a phone. I tried it when  I got back though. I forgot to tell you sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is not actual 'null' equivalent. 
Typically I have used or have seen `-1` used to represent an invalid/null value. 
If of course you don't expect negative numbers.

Comment: Hmm. Intresting. This may work, I technically want the ability to add - numbers. But, at the same time I could treat the - as subtraction rather then actually value. Does Double.parseDouble() do negatives?

Comment: parseDouble does work with negatives, but I didn't think of the Double.NaN` answer given by @Codebender, which is a better solution.

Comment: thanks for understanding. I accepted his. But +1 for your answer because the negatives thing is a good solution for many problems.